# generateAppendClassName: CSS module is undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, deployment, web-deployment, github-pages

I have a React v15 web app that runs fine at localhost. Yet when I deploy it to GitHub pages, I have a `CSS module is undefined` error:

[image]

I've set up a test repo for this issue: https://github.com/ZeningQu/test-repo/tree/master

If you clone the repo and run `yarn start`, you should be able to see the `load-data-pane` component:
[image]

But when you do `yarn run deploy`, the [GitHub page](https://zeningqu.github.io/test-repo/) is basically empty:

[image]

More info:

- [`load-data-pane` component](https://github.com/vega/voyager/blob/master/src/components/load-data-pane/index.tsx)
- [load-data-pane.scss](https://github.com/vega/voyager/blob/master/src/components/load-data-pane/load-data-pane.scss)
- [package.json](https://gist.github.com/ZeningQu/202d9e172ed3e794881696282728cc46)
- [webpack.config.prod.js](https://gist.github.com/ZeningQu/853822e8ec083ca88e4dc832a4161be4)

Comment: Your build has a defect. The CSS file being required is just a string.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your repo to work in my local machine. However, I've had problems with deploying React application before. One trick I learnt was to put `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` tag in `repo/public/index.html`. Maybe you can try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @AlexLuong, I tried adding `<base href="/">` to `<head>` tag, but I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have set the option `auto`: undefied,and this helps me!

```js
{
  loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
  options: {
    modules: {
      auto: useModules ? undefined : false,
      localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
    },
  },
}
```